# FragmentManager getBackStackEntryCount() always zero in SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have an SherlockFragmentActivity which is responsible for adding tabs and adding listeners to those tabs. I add tabs in de following way:

```
public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Styled);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // First add some tabs and give them explaining names
        ActionBar.Tab homeTab = getSupportActionBar()
                               .newTab()
                               .setIcon(R.drawable.home_unselected)
                               .setTabListener(new TabListener<SherlockFragment>(this, "home", HomeFragment.class));

ActionBar.Tab profileTab = getSupportActionBar()
                               .newTab()
                               .setIcon(R.drawable.profile_unselected)
                               .setTabListener(new TabListener<SherlockFragment>(this, "profile", ProfileFragment.class));

    getSupportActionBar().addTab(homeTab);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(profileTab);
}

    public static class TabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener
   {
      private SherlockFragment mFragment;
      private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;
      private final String mTag;
      private final Class<?> mClass;

      /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
       * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
       * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
       * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
       */
      public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<?> clz)
      {
         mActivity = (SherlockFragmentActivity) activity;
         mTag = tag;
         mClass = clz;
      }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check if the fragment has already been initialised
         SherlockFragment  preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

         int resID = mActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(mTag + "_selected" , "drawable", mActivity.getPackageName());
         Drawable image = mActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID);

         tab.setIcon(image);


         if (mFragment != null)
         {

            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);

         }
         else if (preInitializedFragment != null)
         {
            mFragment = preInitializedFragment;
            ft.attach(mFragment);
         }
         else
         {
            // Not found, so instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
         }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(
            com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (mFragment != null) {
                // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
                ft.detach(mFragment);



                int resID = mActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(mTag + "_unselected" , "drawable", mActivity.getPackageName());
                 Drawable image = mActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID);

                tab.setIcon(image);

         }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(
            com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   }
}
```

I want for each tab, that if the tab is selected, the fragment of that tab is pushed to the stack. So when i press back button, i return to the previous fragment instead of activity.

So my guess was to @Override my onBackPressed in my HomeActivity like this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // initialize variables
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    // check to see if stack is empty
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {          
        fm.popBackStack();
        ft.commit();    
    }
    else {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    return;
}
```

But it turns out that `fm.getBackStackEntryCount()` ALWAYS has the value of `0`. So my fragments are never added to the stack. Why aren't they? What am i missing.

Edit :

Not completely solved yet, but i now have the following code:

```
@Override
        public void onTabSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check if the fragment has already been initialised
             SherlockFragment  preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

             int resID = mActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(mTag + "_selected" , "drawable", mActivity.getPackageName());
             Drawable image = mActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID);

             tab.setIcon(image);

             FragmentTransaction transaction = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

             if (mFragment != null)
             {

                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                transaction.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

             }
             else if (preInitializedFragment != null)
             {
                mFragment = preInitializedFragment;
                transaction.attach(mFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
             }
             else
             {
                // Not found, so instantiate and add it to the activity
                mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                transaction.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
             }
        }
```

But now, if the `popBackStack()` method is fired, the content of the fragment becomes empty. Also the icon of the tab stays selected on the last selected tab.

Comment: I don't see where your fragments are added to the backstack. A much easier solution is to keep track in a simple int stack of the order of user selection of tabs. In the `onBackPressed()` you would look at the last element from the stack and simply set the current tab to the tab pointed by that number. I would advise against this, I don't recall seeing many application doing this and it seems a bit problematic for the user(if he goes through the tabs for 20 times, he'll need to click the BACK button 20 times).

Comment: I noticed that Instagram also makes a stack of fragments. If a user accidentally clicks on the back button, it exits the application. This is not the behaviour i want for my application.

Comment: I understand, just keep in mind my example above(the 20 tabs). The backstack works only with `addToBackStack()`, it's in the docs I think http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.html . The problem is the `FragmentTransaction` in those tab callbacks doesn't support being added to the back stack(at least for the sdk listener). You can use the approach from my first comment.

Comment: Thank you for your support. When i clicked 20 tabs through an application and the back button goes back to the previous tab, i just press the home button. Anyway, after adding a tab i just call `ft.addToBackStack()` in my `onTabSelected()` right?

Comment: You could try adding `ft.addToBackStack()` in `onTabSelected()`, but as I said I'm not sure that `FragmentTransaction ft` allows it to be added to the backstack. See how it goes.

Comment: As soon as i'm home, i will try that.

Comment: Made a little adjustment. Could you look into this? `popBackStack()` now is giving my a blank fragment screen. And the icon is not switched back to the previous icon. The `fm.getBackStackEntryCount()` now increments when tabs are selected.

Comment: The icon remaining is normal as you set that manually and the `FragmentManager` can't/doesn't change that, it only works with fragments. The black screen I think it's also normal due to all the attaching/detaching that you do in that method(probably leaving the fragments in an inconsistent state). I would advise you again to simply store the tab number and call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSelectedNavigationItem%28int%29 using the numbers in reverse order. This will also make the icon change accordingly.